# AS3 MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop() Not Working Properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a section of code where I check if the player has collected all coins, and if they have, I wish to move to the game's end screen. The issue is that it stays on the game screen! I know that my conditional statement is correct because I've used a trace statement to check it. The piece of code in question is:

```
if (numCoins - coinsCollected == 0) {
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("GameOverScreen");
}
```

Just for more information; I have a game start screen, a game screen (empty symbol that uses a class linkage for the gameplay) and a game over screen on 3 separate frames. Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Where do you use this code that you've posted? Is it attched to a child of the main timeline? Or is it ON the main timeline?

Comment: It is a child of the main timeline. Oddly enough, there are no errors either - I'd tried just gotoAndStop("GameOverScreen") earlier as if the code was a part of the main timeline, however this is where I got the error (something along the lines of being unable to find the frame).

Comment: And, of course, you DO have a properly labeled frame?

Comment: Yes, labelled frame (I've also tried simply MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(3) to no avail.

Is it possible that this frame is hidden under the game frame? I only ask because if I edit  the code to go to frame 3 and stop while there are still coins on the screen and continue to collect coins, errors occur essentially saying that the coin objects don't exist.

Comment: You should post your complete code for us to see. And a screen shot of your timeline layout. Juat edit your original post.  Whatever is causing your problem it's too trivial too see!

Comment: Thanks Craig, I've figured out the issue. The game over screen was hidden under the game screen objects, so I need to manually remove every game object in order to see the game over screen. I'm not sure why this is the case, just glad that I've figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

If you say, that `gotoAndStop("GameOverScreen");` also doesn't give any result, and if you do all your work in the main class, so 'root' is the same as 'this'. It means only one thing, you missed with reference on MovieClip with 'GameOverScreen' frame.

And to check `numCoins - coinsCollected <= 0` is more secure.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer Nicolas - I'm not quite sure what you mean by "missed with reference on MovieClip with GameOverScreen frame - what is the solution to this?

Comment: How do you redirect user from the Menu to the Game? Try to do it in the same class but from the Game to GameOver.

Comment: I do this in the actions panel in Flash - it's a simple start game button with an event listener: gotoAndStop("GameScreen");